# Forfeit side businesses in order to accept an offer?

Tags: job-offer, contracts

Recently, I received an offer for an executive position at a large firm. I work in the tech industry in Silicon Valley.

On the whole, I'm happy with the proposed job and compensation, benefits etc.

However, they want to to close out my interest in several companies I've built. I'm also not allowed to take on any independent outside projects (even though there is no outside conflict of interest).

Their justification is that they want my "undivided attention".  How common is this at the executive level? It seems that virtually everyone I speak to has other obligations and as long as their no conflict of interests and they do it on their own time there is no issue. That is also currently the practice at my current place of employment.

Is this more common in some parts of the country than others? Is this common everywhere at higher levels? I'm trying to get the lay of the land as to what to expect.

Thanks!

**Edit:** On the whole they have been accommodating of other requests, for example location, etc.

I am curious how people suggest handling this type of situation and if they have seen it before did they end up signing or rejecting?

Comment: Why the downvote? I'm happy to adjust or add more things to my question

Comment: I bet some of the equity partner have side businesses.  Or even serve on boards of other businesses.   Problem here is if you are not happy in a year you cannot just go back into you side businesses.

Answer (score 2):

I am not an executive but if I am hiring someone to run a department or company, I would expect them to give 100% of themselves to the position, not to other companies or a book they are writing or volunteer causes and what-so-ever. If the compensation for this position will eclipse what you are expecting to make from all those companies on the side or royalties from a book deal etc, I think you should seriously consider their offer. Otherwise walk away and be happy with what you got. It seems like you are already at another company and if you want this new position, cost of business is giving up what you have running. You do not have to get rid of those. Just put them into a dormant state and when the time comes up, they trust your judgement, bring them back into daylight, letting them know you want to pick them back up. If they trust you, they should not have any problems but as someone coming from the street as a fresh employee for a highly compensated position, what would you do if you were in that management's position ?

Answer (score 2):

I doubt anyone has reliable statistics on how common or uncommon this is in any particular area. I'm also not sure frequency is significant.

Like everything else on the  contact, it is theoretically negotiable. If an agreement isn't reached, you aren't hired. Both sides have to decide what they are willing to give up to make the hiring happen.

We really can't tell you what to do beyond that. We don't have all the facts and we can't read minds. Make a decision about what this point is worth to you and what you would be willing to trade to keep it or give it up, see if you can make a deal, then -- whatever happens -- never forget that you made the best decision you could the time.